# Pooling Protobuf POJOs

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf as an encoding mechanism for a data recorder. Remote clients will send a message (encoded in protobuf) over TCP, which the application will write to disk. After the message has been written to disk, its only memory reference is dropped, and will be garbage collected in due course.

Due to the high volume of messages I'm expecting (it's particularly "bursty"), I am attempting to optimize the solution.

In an attempt to reduce GC, I would like to pool the protobuf POJOs. Let's assume I'm recording actions, and my protobuf is defined as:

```
message Action {
    required string user;
    required long time;
    required string action;
}
```

This generates me the required code, including the static methods `Action.parseFrom(byte[])`, which I am using to read-in objects from the TCP socket. Each time this is invoked, it calls `PARSER.parsePartialFrom(...)`, which creates **a new Action object for each received message**.

I cannot see any option within the API to be able to provide a pool of these objects which could be re-used to re-cycle the `Action` POJO, unless I hack the generated code and check it into source control (which I'm not willing to do).

Any suggestions?

I also have similar problems when creating messages on the client-side. Each call to `buildPartial()` creates a new POJO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's official Java Protobuf implementation (which I wrote) does not support this, since it favors immutability as a design quality. For large JVM-based servers, this usually works out well, as the GC is pretty good with short-lived objects.

However, this does cause problems for some use cases and especially on mobile. To that end, a number of people have written alternative Java Protobuf implementations specifically focused on more constrained environments. Perhaps one of them would work well for you. The list is here:

https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md